# Tracing 500 Errors in Sitecore Personalize & CDP - Failure to Execute Flow

Tags: cdp, sitecore-personalize

While having the network tab open in F12, one of the responses indicates a `500` error. Inspecting the response reveals a developer message but no friendly name of the actual object, only a GUID.

```
Failure to execute flow ref=\{your guid here}\
```

Answer (score 1):

To trace and address the issue:

```
Settings Cog > Your Login > Feature Flags > debug enabled
```

Take note of the `browser ID`

Navigate to Guests and search for bid:`{enter browser id here}`

View the various events on the timeline, starting with the most recent, view details

With debug enabled, a cog will show after the title such as "Events for Session"

View as JSON

Search for the GUID that was described in the "flow" attribute

Within the JSON object you will see the name and type of the root cause, such as a failing web experiment

Fix the experiment or set it to pause or finish[image]